# Importing schema with XMLmapper in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, schema, xmlmapper

I try to import some valid schema (for xmlspy and oxygen) with XMLMapper in delphi and I have this error

"Error Flux if:InfofileType unknown".

I use namespace and this type is define in another file.

Is there a way to solve this ?

(I also try with Delphi 2010 demo and it still not work)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:if="http://www.gtest.fr/Apps/InfoFile" xmlns:ca="http://www.gtest.fr/Apps/CommandAnswer" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.gtest.fr/Apps/InfoFile" schemaLocation="InfoFile.xsd" /> 
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.gtest.fr/Apps/CommandAnswer" schemaLocation="CommandAnswer.xsd" /> 
- <xs:element name="ServerAnswer">
- <xs:annotation>
  <xs:documentation>Reponse serveur socket</xs:documentation> 
  </xs:annotation>
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="InfoFile" type="if:InfoFileType" /> 
  <xs:element name="Command" type="ca:CommandAnswerType" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

reported in QC : http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=80124

Comment: "(I don't use Delphi 2010)" So what version **do** you use?

Comment: It make the same with Delphi 2010

Comment: Ist the XSD file InfoFile.xsd there? - See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-0/#import

Comment: @mjustin : all my schemas are in the same directory

Answer (score 1):

I would still try to grab a Delphi 2010 (trial) and see if it works there.
I know there has been significant work done there in D2009 and D2010. It was notoriously bad at doing imports and includes.
Much better now...
If you cannot solve this, I would recommend to manually edit the schemas to remove the include/import and build a big fat XSD without the external file. It should work better.
That's how I did with a rather intricate set of schemas that even .Net lib would choke on.

**Update**: Could you try to replace the if:InfoFile by another symbol to avoid any clash with the if reserved word; i.e. search 'n' replace if in the schemas by _if_ or anything else...  The XML mapper is supposed to care of this but, ya know...

Comment: Installed and it is the same :(

Comment: Pleas submit a bug report in QC with the schema files attached.  
In the meantime, you can either try to see if it imports with Delphi Prism (the .Net importer) and manually edit the code for Delphi, or tweak the schemas into 1 big XSD.  
I know it can be frustrating! Been there, done that :-(

Answer (score 0):

Eric Thorniley finally give me the way to go [here](https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=201085#201085).

> It seems XML Mapper does not
>   understand the namespaces correctly.
>   You can however coax it into life by
>   adding an extra namespace definition
>   into the imported files. This is, I am
>   sure, not right.
>
> So, for instance, in your
>   Insurance.xsd you declare
>   xmlns:Utils="http://www.gtest.fr/Apps/Utils"
>
> If you add exactly the same definition
>   into Utils.xsd, XML Mapper imports it
>   correctly (I think!)
>
> Ther is a fair chance that XML Spy
>   would strip out my modifications -
>   certainly Enterprise Architect ignores
>   them completely.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to see the message that Eric Thorniley pointed you to, but it is no longer there.  I might be able to find it in an archive somewhere, if I had the subject of the message.  I tried a Google search but all I found were duplicate copies of this post on different sites.

Thanks